# Python: joblib freezes (only) when run via bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, multiprocessing

I'm connected to a cluster via SSH, running Python scripts on it for data science purposes and some of the scripts are parallelized.

I use 2 methods for executing scripts on the cluster:

- PyCharm deployment & remote interperter (port forwarding + tunneling).
- Executing from a bash script.

My code runs smoothly when I run it on PyCharm or using a bash script, but only on very small datasets. When I run it on larger datasets (=> larger number of tasks) using the bash script, it freezes once it reaches close to the end of the tasks. No error/warning are shown, it's just that the parallel computation is stuck (example below). Issue always occurs on the last tasks, whether 1,000 tasks should be completed, or 100,000 - it doesn't matter.

**Example freeze output (5000 tasks should've been done):**

```
...
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 4889 tasks      | elapsed:   50.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 4890 tasks      | elapsed:   50.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 4891 tasks      | elapsed:   50.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=32)]: Done 4892 tasks      | elapsed:   50.1s
[Pa
```

**Python script essentials:**

Parallelization command is of the form:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
result = Parallel(n_jobs=N_CORES)(delayed(FUNCTION)(ARGUMENTS) for i in xrange(n))
```

ARGUMENTS and FUNCTION include numpy & pandas arrays.

**The bash script I use:**

```
#!/bin/sh

/storage/home/username/.conda/envs/conaenv/bin/python2.7 /storage/home/username/script.py 2>&1  | tee /storage/home/username/log.txt

exit 0
```

In order to solve it I tried:

- Using both joblib & multiprocessing (issue occurs on both).
- Specifying a timeout to exit parallel computation and capture only part of the results, but there was no response to timeout.
- Try/Catch any error in the parallelized FUNCTION, but no error captured.
- setting joblib environment variable 'JOBLIB_START_METHOD' to 'forkserver'.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this issue by now?

Comment: As I understand it, the job wasn't actually frozen at all.
It is most likely that the code following the Parallel() function was already running in the background, but its output wasn't shown (the reason for that is yet unknown).
Since the code that followed it involved very heavy computations, it seemed completely stuck in every practical manner.

Comment: meaning that if you just didn't touch it over night, the program would have correctly processed everything and finished accordingly?

Comment: In my case it was more than a night, but basically yes. It is worth trying that if you are facing a similar issue.